# pylons RESTful API methods (get, put, post, and detete)

Tags: python, rest, pylons

I am new in using the pylon framework and i am trying to use
the RESTful API methods. I dont know how to use those methods, i have
looked at the book (http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/exploring-pylons.html#exploring-the-environment)
but it only gives example of request.params so can someone please explain how do i use 
the methods and how can i test that the controller is responding to POST, PUT etc...

Answer (score 1):

I use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) (an efficient feature-rich command line tool):

GET

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:5000/CONTROLLER/ACTION/ID
```

POST

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "param1=value1" http://localhost:5000/CONTROLLER/ACTION
```

PUT

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d "param1=value1" http://localhost:5000/CONTROLLER/ACTION/ID
```

DELETE

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X DELETE http://localhost:5000/CONTROLLER/ACTION/ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE might have capabilities for testing it.

You can test any REST api fairly similarly from the browser.  Check out this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349618/what-tools-can-i-use-to-test-a-rest-api

Personally, I usually write custom javascript using [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for testing a rest api.  Or for simple GET's, just the URL in the browser.  If you are programming with the [pycharm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), their latest version has an awesome built in tool for this.

As for programming the interface - have a look at [rest4api](http://code.google.com/p/rest4sql/) - I believe it's a rest api framework built with pylons.